# About to re-enter the UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

My case - and history -

I carry a passport that the visa (tourist/leave to enter) is issued at the airport (non-EU). I arrived end of 2016 and  received 6 months (a lucky day ). I left after 1 month only (a very unlucky day).

Is it better to travel before those 6 months are over;  i.e., is there such a regulation, that if immigration already issued a certain time (based on the evidence I brought with me and such), will the next immigration officer issue easily a visa for the time remaining from those 6 months?

Is the time of travel irrelevant and will it be completely a new case when I arrive in the UK?

I am trying to read the UK regulations and I cannot find a certain green light for the free travel thing, nor can I understand it.

From persons I've met, sometimes they were given 2 weeks or a month, etc . If everything is at the discretion of the immigration officer, what are my chances to get those 6 months per year ? I know about proof of funds. What steps should I take?

Comment: They will take into account your history of travel. If the ECO thinks you are not a genuine visitor but trying to effectively settle in the UK, they can decline to grant you leave to enter.

Comment: If you receive an entry stamp at the airport then that is not a visa.  The standard period of admission for such people is six months.

Comment: Regarding **"I cannot find a certain green light for the free travel thing"** it's in the rules.

Answer (score 8):

Non-visa nationals who arrive in the UK for business or tourism will *by default* get leave to enter for 6 months, unless the immigration officer who processes them finds something amiss with their explanation.

Such a leave to enter *automatically expires* when you leave the UK. This is stated in [Paragraph 20A of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk)...

> Leave to enter or remain in the United Kingdom will usually lapse on
>   the holder going to a country or territory outside the common travel
>   area.

The next time you apply to enter, you can get a **new** leave to enter for 6 months, if you still don't trigger the IO's suspicions.

The precise number of days you have used of your previous leave to enter is not important. What **is** important is that you don't give the IO the impression that you're trying to live primiarily in the UK and just exiting temporarily in order to get a fresh leave to enter. If he gets that impression, you're likely to be refused outright, or be given a very short leave to enter so you can bring your affairs in order and then leave voluntarily -- it's never "6 months minus what you have already used up".

(Also important is whether the time you stayed in the UK matched what you said when you entered, *even if you left within the time your LtE was valid for*. If you changed your plans dramatically and can't explain that satisfactorily afterwards, your credibility will be hurt. We have seen cases of travelers who were refused entry for this reason).

---

Note in passing that the leave to enter you get at the border is **not a visa**. A visa is something you apply for *in advance*.

Comment: Where does it say leave automatically expires when you leave the UK?  Is there a source?

Comment: @GayotFow: That's what I think [sections 20 and 20A](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk) say. Is there a relevant difference between "expire" and "lapse" in this context?

Comment: Good research, Sir, I have updated your answer and added my up vote because it's technically complete